# how to edit text in a text box that was set using Text box.text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i cant edit the text that's in the text box. i need the textbox to show text at the start which then can be edited.
imageName shows up in the text box but i cant edit it to something else.

```
private void image_NameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imageName = (dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[selectedIndex]["Image Name"].ToString());

        image_NameTextBox.Text = imageName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you defined a TextChanged-Event to your TextBox. Every time you edit your Text you are calling your handler:

```
private void image_NameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imageName = (dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[selectedIndex]["Image Name"].ToString());

        image_NameTextBox.Text = imageName;
    }
```

The result is: You are setting the Text back to the old value.

Remove the event from your TextBox and fill your Text in a different methode.

Answer (score 0):

You have your code in the `TextChanged` event which means everytime you try and edit the text it just sets it right back to the same thing. Move your code outside of the `TextChanged` event (somewhere it is still functional) and then try editing your text.